# How to show forested areas in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, basemap

Was wondering if someone could give me some pointers for a project I am working on. 
I need to create a map to show nest sites for Coopers Hawk from 2001. I have lat/long data for each point I will need to add. If I add a base layer map and add points with lat/long, is there a way to show forested areas in a very basic shape? Grey or shapes with a pattern fill; I would like this map to be as clean as possible. I will then have a smaller map to the side (vicinity map) showing where in ND this study site is located.

Below is an example map from Google that is similar to the look I'm after. However my final product will have only one classification for forested area, not several. And will of course have 21 points plotted showing the Nest sites for these accipiters.

[image]

Comment: If you've got the data then, sure, you can show it. Add the layer for the forests which will come up with some basic symbology obscuring everything underneath, click on the symbol for the layer then pan down to the bottom (ish) of the symbol sector - there's some good tree types there, edit the symbol (button on right, middle) and set the background colour to 'no colour' so you can see underneath. If you can include a picture of what you're roughly after I'm sure we can help.

Comment: do you need black and white, or can you use colors ?

Comment: I would prefer to keep grayscale but. Nests be represented by single black dots and then forested areas could be gray or a pattern of lines. I will do a quick sketch of what Im visioning the final product to be. I just didnt know if I start by adding baselayer and zoom into the study site, add all points, then add forested layer somehow. I have 21 points I will be plotting on this map.  All pointers are welcomed. GIS looks to be awesome software Im excited to learn. Have a great day!

Comment: If you want to display the forested areas in some particular manner, you need to have them as their own dataset you can manipulate/symbolize. It's not clear from your question if this is the case ("add forested layer *somehow*"). If you don't, you could easily create a new polygon feature class/shapefile, trace the boundaries from an imagery basemap or other source at whatever level of detail/accuracy you desire, and then symbolize those polygons however you like. Also, you should **edit** your question with the button at the lower left to include details requested in comments.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice thus far. I am going to add baselayer and all lat/long points tonight and go from there. I have a rough sketch of what I am imgining for final product but was unsure if I could post a picture or if that was bad form. Im sure this project is a simple one but am brand new to this. :)

Comment: Welcome to the site Maddie.  It would be helpful to include a map that you find online resembling what you envision to help guide readers.  If you have found a solution, please add it as a solution so his question can be considered resolved. As an aside, you can classify imagery to define forested and non-forested areas (e.g. supervised classification).  Then use this raster layer in your map.

Comment: You can (and are encouraged to when relevant) include images in your question. There's an insert picture button above the post box when editing.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have pointed out, you need a polygon dataset of the forested areas to symbolize in whatever manner you choose on top of the base map. You could get these by:

- Creating a new polygon feature class/shapefile and editing it to
  [trace around the boundaries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_1b_Digitizing_lines_and_snapping/01m60000001z000000/) of forest from an imagery base map.
- Running a classification on an image as Aaron suggests (and either
  using the resulting raster or vectorizing it to polygons - polygons
  will have more control over what symbology is possible). You could
  use the image from the base map or locate some land cover data in
  raster form.
- Locate forest polygons from another source that are ready to go. USGS
  may have some (such as DLGs that are linework from a quad sheet), or
  the USFS might, or local colleges, county/state governments, etc.

Once you have the polygons, you can add that layer between your base map imagery layer on the bottom and points layer on the top. You'll symbolize by feature (Properties of layer, Symbology tab) and can set the patch to whatever you like - a solid color with no outline (perhaps add some transparency on the Display tab), just an outline with no fill, a hatched/pattern fill... there are numerous options.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is not with digitizing or polygons, but by using the [National Land Cover Database](http://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd2011.php), which is a 30m resolution raster, and should look great for a whole township as you have in your post.

My favorite way to obtain the NLCD for any state is through the [NRCS Geospatial Data Gateway](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/), just follow the "Order by State" link on the right side of the page.  You can get all sorts of other goverment-created data through that gateway as well.  It's free, a download link will be sent to you once you complete the order.

When you get the raster downloaded and unzipped, just add it into arcmap and you'll see all of the different land cover types coded by color and number.  The default colors will match [this legend](http://www.mrlc.gov/nlcd11_leg.php), but you can remove classes or change their color all you want.    Or, if you do want cross-hatching or patterned fill, you could convert the raster to polygons and go from there.